# Spring maven webapp configuration - Did not find handler method for images

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm building an application with Maven + Spring, webapp archetype

In the image there is my directory tree.
The images are in the webapp/public directory

[image]

They are correctly deployed in tomcat in /svgTest/public/images

I try to link them in my jsp pages in this way:

```
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/public/images/disegno.svg" />
```

The link is correct, but in the logs I see

```
2016-03-02 11:52:33.192 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-55]: Looking up handler method for path /public/images/disegno.svg
2016-03-02 11:52:33.192 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-55]: Did not find handler method for [/public/images/disegno.svg]
2016-03-02 11:52:33.192 WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-55]: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/svgTest/public/images/disegno.svg] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

My AppConfig.java is very simple:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("it.besmart")

public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{


    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public StandardServletMultipartResolver resolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public SVGParser parser(){
        return new SVGParser();
    }

}
```

and this is my AppInitializer.java

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }


}
```

What is missing?

Comment: You need to add request handler to `ResourceHandlerRegistry` for the spring to identify your resources. or you can move your imges to `resources`

Comment: enable default resource handling. Override the `configureDefaultServletHandling` and on the `configurer` call `enabled()`. This will delegate requests the dispatcher servlet cannot handle to the underlying container.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this structure

webapp-resources-images-xyz.svg